# Gradle project refresh failed - Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio-2.1.1 and created a new project named **MyApplication** . It is throwing following error :

> Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
>
> Error : A problem occured configuring project ':app'.

I visited many similar links on stackoverflow , finally I uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio , still I am getting the same problem .

[image]

Comment: Press on the "Show Log in Explorer" button on the upper right corner and paste related exceptions

Comment: Gradle is horrible wished they would use something that didn't take 3Gig ! of memory.  Seems no one now-a-days can write efficient code anymore.